# Visual Studio 2017 not showing preconfigured devices

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have created a Xamarin Forms app by going through File->New Project->Cross-Platform->Mobile App.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise edition and would like to run this app in Android emulator.

As per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-sdk-emulator/running-the-emulator?tabs=vswin), Visual Studio includes pre-configured virtual devices that appear in the device drop-down menu.

However, I don't see any of those virtual devices listed

[image]

What do I need to do to have those emulators listed?

Comment: tools->android->android emulator manager?

Comment: That is empty. So I used this link https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/ to download the emulators. I can even run the emulator. But to make visual studio run this project on emulator since its not showing up in the listing

Comment: did you try restarting visual studio after creating a new emulator device? I've had it before where they didn't appear until restarted

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Apparently, above link shows the following note from Microsoft - "Note: After we released the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, Google updated their Android emulator to use hardware acceleration through Intel’s HAXM.

We recommend you use Google’s emulator when you can, as it offers access to the latest Android OS images and Google Play services."

Comment: Visual Studio Emulator for Android is discontinued and only works with Visual Studio 2013/2015.

Comment: glad it's working for you. I've added it as an answer. with regards to the Visual studio emulator for android, I miss it too. imo the google ones still arn't quite as good. although they have definitely improved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools->Android->Emulator manager.

Create a new device

Restart visual studio